# HTML Special characters show as question mark on one server but not the other

Tags: html, wordpress, special-characters

I have a wordpress website in which I am using some sort of calendar in multiple languages. In french the special characters ô... are displayed perfectly on the staging server, but are converted to question marks on the live server. Can anyone help point out how to solve this ?

The dates are generated by php:

```
$langCode = "fr_FR";
setlocale(LC_ALL, $langCode);
$MysqlDate = strtotime(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'date', TRUE));
$month = ucwords(strftime("%b", $MysqlDate));
```

Also in the head utf-8 is set

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: sounds like have forgotten to specify charset on the server? eg `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

setlocale  depends on system, specially if you using windows, If you provide a code page like UTF-7 or UTF-8, setlocale will fail, returning NULL.

Here check msdn reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d.aspx

Comment: The locale must work because the months are displayed in frech.

Answer (score 0):

I want to point you something, that is not very well known: you can add charset info to `setlocale()`.

Example:

Into my `utf-8-encoded` page I want to insert the name of the current month, which happens to be March, in German "März" - with umlaut. If you use:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE');
echo strftime("%B");
```

...this will return "März", but that html-entity will look like this on a `utf-8` page: "M?rz" with question mark. Not what I want.

But if you use:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE.UTF8');  // note the charset info !
echo strftime("%B");
```

...this returns "M√§rz", which, on utf-8, looks like it should: "März".

The same solution will apply to French, just put charset info when calling `setlocale()`.